# React mapped checkbox repeating back all of the array elements, instead of just the ones i've checked

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, reactjs

[Visual: Form I am using on the left, outputs on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwyRM.png)

I'm trying to use a checkbox array map in React to show features of a certain thing, but when I print out the elements every array element shows up on the table of my front-end webpage after I submit my form and in my database instead of just the ones i've checked. It's all being reported back to a MongoDB database, and thats working fine (I checked by changing what I send there to a simple String input and that showed up fine), so I am positive the mapping is the issue. Thanks!

Constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        name: '',
        price: '',
        location: ['Back Bay', 'Downtown Crossing'],
        description: '',
        features: [
            'Pet-Free', 'Climate-Controlled', 'Locked Area', 'Private Entrance', 'Smoke Detectors', 'Smoke Free'
        ],
    };

        this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);

    this.addListingService = new ListingService();
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
```

And here is my mapping:

```
<div>What cool features does this storage space have?</div>
  {
   this.state.features.map((features) => {
              return <CheckBox key={features} title={features} name="features" />
             })
               }
```

Edit:

I also tried to use an onInputChange() function to see if that would trigger it so only the checkbox options I checked would appear on my front-end page and my database, but that did not seem to help. I've attached a photo showing the form I am using and the outputs. Here is that function:

```
        onInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value,
        });
    }
```

Edit 2:

I'm now trying key mapping as suggested below, but am getting an error with the ObjectKeys function. The error I receive says "TypeError: Object.assign(...).filter is not a function"

```
   Object.keys(this.state.features).map(key =>({...this.state.features[key],title:key}
                                    .filter(features=>features.checked)
                                    .map(features => <CheckBox key={features} title={features} onChange = {this.onInputChange} />)))
```

Comment: I don't get it. Are you saying you don't want unchecked ones being rendered? If so, where's that conditional logic? Your mapping just renders an element per array with no condition.

Comment: Yup! I only want it to report back ones that I have checked, then they're fed to my database and I can list them on my page.

Comment: I previously tried to do onChange{this.onInputChange}, but that did not seem to help. Here is that function:

            onInputChange(event) {
            const target = event.target;
            const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
            const name = target.name;

            this.setState({
                [name]: value,
            });
        }

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show certain elements of an array you can use Array.prototype.filter

```
this.state.features
    .filter(features=>features.checked)
    .map(feature => <CheckBox key={feature.id} title={feature.title} name="features" />)
```

This will only display check boxes for the items you have checked. When you return true to filter it keeps the item, false does not. Note: this does not modify your original array. My method requires you to refactor your data slightly though. You might want an array of features that looks like

```
[
    {id:1,title:'Pet-Free',checked:true},
    {id:2,title:'Climate-Controlled',checked:false},
    // ...etc
]
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot and let you know, thanks so much!

Comment: I may not have articulated my problem as well as I intented, the issue is that  when I check 3/6 items, all 6 show up vs. just the 3 I want to. I tried your solution and whichever features have checked:true show up no matter if they are checked or not, instead of only showing up if I physically check them on my front-end page. I had both id 1 and 2 as checked:true, and they showed up on my front-end page and in my database as [object Object],[object Object]. Let me know if that clarifies my issue, thanks again!

Comment: Can you explain to me where the checkbox is defined as checked or not? Maybe I'd you edit your answer with the code of CheckBox that may help.

Comment: I didn't have it defined as checked or not, as the only example I could find with isChecked only included 1 checkbox and reported either true or false, instead of the title/value of the checkbox (i.e. "pet-free")

Comment: What if you did a data structure as such {"Pet-Free":{id:1,checked:true}} Then for onInputChange do onInputChange={e=>this.setState({features:{...this.state.features,[e.target.name]:{...this.state.features[e.target.name],checked:e.target.checked}}} then for the viewing array you'll have to do Object.keys(this.state.features).map(key=>({...this.state.features[key],title:key}).filter(feature=>feature.checked).map(etc)

Comment: Receiving this error: TypeError: Object.assign(...).filter is not a function

Comment: Oh and that error is happening on the Object.keys... line.Thanks! @DanielAbdelsamad

Comment: Sorry I was typing that late at night and on my phone so I couldn't type anything complicated. I forgot to put parentheses when the object type changed. Use this instead for the render function (Object.keys(this.state.features)).map(key=>({...this.state.fe‌​atures[key],title:ke‌​y}).filter(feature=>‌​feature.checked).map‌​(feature => <CheckBox key={feature.id} title={feature.title} name="features" />). Notice the extra parentheses around Object.keys. This tells the compiler to recompute the type. By default its going to chain functions, parentheses denote a type change.

Comment: No worries! I'm still getting the TypeError: Object.assign(...).filter is not a function error sadly. Here's how I have the code, its inside my render:

                             <div>Feats?</div>
                                {
                                    (Object.keys(this.state.features)).map(key=>({...this.state.features[key],title:key})
                                        .filter(feature=>feature.checked).map(feature =>
                                            <CheckBox key={feature.id} title={feature.title} name="features" />)
                                }

Comment: Wow I am stupid. I am missing a parentheses! (Object.keys(this.state.features)).map(key=>({...this.state.‌​fe‌​atures[key],titl‌​e:ke‌​y})).filter(fea‌​ture=>‌​feature.chec‌​ked).map‌​(feature => <CheckBox key={feature.id} title={feature.title} name="features" />) There was another parentheses before filter that I forgot, sorry about that!

Comment: If this works for you, I'll go ahead and create a new answer so you can mark it as correct for others if they need it

Comment: Almost there, the array elements aren't showing up on the front-end though, I have 2 and each has an id and is checked:true, but they aren't popping up. You've been a great help! Once they show up I think ill be good to go, any ideas on that would be awesome but you've helped a ton

Comment: Any chance you could whip up a jsfiddle or a codepen (I recommend CodePen) to show me some actual code, it will be much easier for me to diagnose